# JAXBException in webservices implementation - <PropertyName> is not a valid property

Tags: jax-ws

I am using JAX-WS to implement web services. I have generated the client and service code using weblogic tools. The web service is hosted successfully. When I ping the service using the end point url from the browser, I am able to see the WSDL's. But when I try to invoke the service from a simple java program, I am getting "JAXBException -  is not a valid property on class "

Can anyone let me know as to where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a fix to this problem in the [JbossWS faq](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossWS-FAQ#Why_Im_getting_propertyname_is_not_valid_property_on_class_mypackagejaxwsPropertyname).

If you need more help on the topic, post some of your code here and I'll see what I can do.